# I'm creating stack overflow clone website but that shows Uncaught Type Error I can't able to get what is it

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm making stack clone but getting error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'result')
at handleSubmit (AskQuestion.jsx:20:1)

I'm not able to get how to solve this issue I want to send data to my backend database mongoDB but, it shows error again and again from long time.

**This is my AskQuestion.js**

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

import './AskQuestion.css'
import { askQuestion } from '../../actions/question'

const AskQuestion = () => {
  const [questionTitle, setQuestionTitle] = useState('')
  const [questionBody, setQuestionBody] = useState('')
  const [questionTags, setQuestionTags] = useState('')

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const User = useSelector((state) => (state.currentUserReducer))
  const navigate = useNavigate()


  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
    //   console.log({questionTitle, questionBody, questionTags})
      dispatch(askQuestion({ questionTitle, questionBody, questionTags, userPosted: User.result.name }, navigate))
  }
  
  const handleEnter = (e) => {
    if(e.key=== 'Enter'){
        setQuestionBody(questionBody + "\n")
    }
  }

  return (
          <div className="ask-question">
              <div className="ask-ques-container">
                <h1>Ask a Public Question</h1>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="ask-form-container">
                        <label htmlFor="ask-ques-title">
                            <h4>Title</h4>
                            <p>Be specific and imagine you're asking a question to another person.</p>
                            <input type="text" name="questionTitle" id="ask-ques-title" onChange={(e) => {setQuestionTitle(e.target.value)}} placeholder="e.g. Is there an R function for finding the index of an element in a vector?"/>
                        </label>
                        <label htmlFor="ask-ques-body">
                            <h4>Body</h4>
                            <p>Introduce the problem and expand on what you put in the title. Minimum 20 characters.</p>
                            <textarea name="" id="ask-ques-body" onChange={(e) => {setQuestionBody(e.target.value)}} cols="30" rows="10" onKeyUp = {handleEnter} ></textarea>
                        </label>
                        <label htmlFor="ask-ques-tags">
                            <h4>Tags</h4>
                            <p>Add up to 5 tags to describe what your question is about. Start typing to see suggestions.</p>
                            <input type="text" id="ask-ques-tags" onChange={(e) => {setQuestionTags(e.target.value.split(" "))}} placeholder="e.g. (wpf mysql ruby-on-rails)"/>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value='Review your question' className='review-btn'/> 
                </form>
              </div>
          </div>
  )
}

export default AskQuestion
```

```js
const currentUserReducer = ( state=null, action ) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "FETCH_CURRENT_USER":
            return action.payload;
            default:
                return state;

    }
}

export default currentUserReducer;
```

**Please help me in solving .result problem to complete the code**

Comment: It looks like `User` is null, meaning that `state.currentUserReducer` is null - check if you are extracting the right thing from your reducer, or if it has a reasonable default value. Also the `User` variable should be in lowercase.

Comment: see, I add Reducer dependency in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read `User.result` when `User` is undefined. Try wrapping the dispatch in a type check:

```js
if(User){
  dispatch(askQuestion({ questionTitle, questionBody, questionTags, userPosted: User.result.name }, navigate));
}
```

Comment: Error is solved but, no data is getting saved in my mongoDB

Comment: That's because User is not set. There's something wrong with your reducer function - try troubleshooting that.

Comment: how to do troubleshoot them? Can I send you the code? can you correct it?